# Firebase Cloud Functions Invalid tag name "glob" error in my Command Line

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I following [this](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da) link to organize my firebase cloud functions and not have all my code in one index.ts file. However, when I'm running the line:

```
npm i -S glob, camelcase
```

in my console, it's retuning this:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "glob,": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/johndoe/.npm/_logs/2018-12-24T19_46_03_264Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm i glob camelcase` instead.  The comma is not correct here.  The -S is not even a documented flag for npm (at least not on the man page for my installation).